# Ads opening up in Internet Explorer automatically

Tags: internet-explorer, virus, advertisements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

I have some bug or virus I guess wherein ads are getting opened in Internet Explorer automatically.

Why is this happening? How do I stop it?

Answer (score 4):

First, go to Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features (assuming Windows 7) and uninstall anything that's toolbar or search related (such as MyWebSearch, Happy Search Assistant, *anything* from Ask.com, etc.).  Take that opportunity to uninstall things you aren't using as well.

Second, go back to the Control Panel and open up Internet Properites.  On the Advanced tab, there is an option in the bottom of the dialog that will reset all Internet Explorer settings to defaults.  Do this.

Third, go [download and run the free version of MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/).  Use the full system scan option, let it run to completion, and use it's delete option on anything it finds.

Finally, go back to the Control Panel again and apply all outstanding important Windows updates.  Also make sure any Adobe and Java products are updated to their latest versions.

Comment: Also, consider installing Microsoft Security Essentials when this is all over. It is a pretty great (and free) AV solution.